Importing ldap data throws issue with memberof
I exported my openldap using slapcat -n 1 -l directory.ldif
When I import to my newer openldap using slapadd -n 1 -l directory.ldif I get the following error:
register_at: AttributeType "( 1.2.840.113556.1.2.102 NAME 'memberOf' DESC 'Group that the entry belongs to' SYNTAX '1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.12' EQUALITY distinguishedNameMatch USAGE dSAOperation NO-USER-MODIFICATION X-ORIGIN 'iPlanet Delegated Administrator' )": Duplicate attributeType, 1.2.840.113556.1.2.102

It will write the first user in the file, but won't populate any memberOf data.  I had issues adding this schema, but when I remove it, it worked as there was no longer a duplicate.  How can I fix this?
Thanks.
Edit: In browsing the ldap with JXplorer, I see the following.


I'm not sure if these are both needed, or causing a conflict.
Edit (Delayed due to Covid, sorry!):
I am running openldap 2.6.8_0+overlays
Schema are:
core
cosine
nis
inetorgperson
passwordselfreset

I would try to to remove the memberOf attributeType definition from directory.ldif before running slapadd. Also I don't think the slapconf cmd exists, did you mean slapcat (for the export) ?

Good catch, thanks.

You exported with slapcat the database "-1" and tried to reimport it in the database "1" .
The frontend database "-1" is part of the server configuration and can't be loaded in a mdb database ("1" in your case)

It would be more helpful with more information about the LDAP server (version, list of schemas which are loaded mannually, etc)
Assuming you are using a recent OpenLDAP version 2.5+ / 2.6+ and that you have manually imported a schema in the cn=schema,cn=config branch
Your problem is probably because the memberOf overlay now loads dynamically the memberOf schema without you needing to do it manually.
You should have in the cn=module{0},cn=config entry an attribute like: olcModuleLoad: memberof.la
This ModuleLoad already takes care of loading the schema to use the memberOf attribute
See. https://github.com/openldap/openldap/blob/d8b5bfddb798147496b888614b7e9b0d811a9869/servers/slapd/overlays/memberof.c#L1752

Looking in config, {0}config I am unable to see olcModuleLoad in my directory config.  This is something I should see in my config.ldif export?  I added schemas and version to my question.
